# With an address, how to get the store opening hours at that address in Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I can't get Google Maps Autocomplete to return the correct place_id for an address I am trying. For example, when I select "298 W McKinley Ave, Sunnyvale, CA 94086, United States" in Autocomplete service, it returns place_id: ChIJtc3P4122j4ARl7eqhmjB3ow, but no store hours in the results.

```
var place = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(element[0], {});
google.maps.event.addListener(place, 'place_changed', function() {
   console.log("place: " + JSON.stringify(place.getPlace()));
});
```

But if I query PlacesService with place_id: ChIJqUSz4l22j4ARRjulQFPISrw, it returns the same address, with store hours this time.

```
 var request = {
   placeId: 'ChIJqUSz4l22j4ARRjulQFPISrw'
};

var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
  console.log("place details: " + JSON.stringify(place));
});
```

Please see http://plnkr.co/edit/vEMO0ls4aIHLgAnGJg3g?p=preview.

Is there a way to get Autocomplete to return the place_id that corresponds to the store at that address? Or with an address, is there any way to get the place_id of the store at that address?